# Number of fields in one object PHP function

Tags: php, json, function

My JSON look like this

```
{
 "type":"row",
 "data":[
    ["polimi","100"]
  ]
}
```

And I would like to know how many keys/attributes the object "data" has through a PHP function if it does exist any..
In this case for example there are 2 attributes in data object

Comment: jscon decode then you have an array and then it should be really easy

Comment: How exactly do you define a "key/attribute" here? That's an array with 2 elements, could there be more and more-dimensional arrays…?

Comment: isn't that data has 1 element and data[0] has 2?